# INSERT VALUE WHERE NOT EXIST with Sqlite?

Tags: android, sqlite

Does this statement:

```
INSERT INTO table (...)
VALUES (...) 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (...)
```

exists using Sqlite3?

EDIT:

```
INSERT OR IGNORE
```

Is not working in my case

Comment: you can use defaults while creating tables and finally where ever that default value is there you can insert your value

Comment: @war_Hero But what happen if the value I'm trying to add is already on the table? I need to check that

Comment: you were doing where not exist right  that means where values dont exist

Comment: WHERE would be part of a SELECT statement. See the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html).

Comment: Hi CL, Sorry I didnt see your comment. You are right, I will edit my question.

Answer (score 0):

please use this method to check if value exist in database or not.its very easy and proper way..i hope its useful to you.

```
 public boolean isRecordExist(String TableName, String columnName,
                                        String value) {
           DbHelper  dbHelper = new DbHelper(this);
            dbHelper.createDataBase();
            SQLiteDatabase sqldb = dbHelper.openDataBase();
        String Query = "Select * from " + TableName + " where " + columnName
                + "='" + value + "'";
        Cursor cursor = sqldb.rawQuery(Query, null);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() <= 0) {
            cursor.close();
            return false;

        } else if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
        return true;

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for that :) However, I'm looking also for a way to do that without using any java code ( where the aim is to generate my db using only sqlite and then use this db in android studio, in order to avoid the device to execute any request conerning the creation of the db )

Comment: i think its not possible without java code,..if you have find solution for that then plz put in to this.

Comment: Sure. I'm gonna edit my main post. Thanks again for your android solution, it will be useful for me during my further tasks.

Comment: if its really helpful then upvote it.

Comment: This does not answer the question. And using [queryNumEntries()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html#queryNumEntries%28android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) would be simpler.

Comment: public void insertCommand(ContentValues values) {  
  if (!isRecordExist(db,table, values)) {    
   //insert you record
  }   
 } 
 private boolean isExist(SQLiteDatabase db,String table, ContentValues data) {  
        StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
        Set<String> keys  = data.keySet();
        for(String key : keys){   
            sql.append(key).append("=").append(data.get(key)).append(" AND ");
        }
  //Remove last appended " AND " before proceed
        String q= sql.toString();
        return DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db,table,q) == 0 ? false : true;  
 }

Comment: This cannot be done in sqllite but you can do some work in java like I have posted above. You can test it this way
 synchronized (LOCK) {
   SQLiteDatabase db = getdb();   
   ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
   values.put(DBInterfaces.COMMANDS.COMMAND, "test");
   values.put(DBInterfaces.COMMANDS.VALUE, "test");
   insertCommand(values);
   db.close();   
  }